# Assuming a theory is a set of logic sentences, what makes a theory weaker than another in propositional logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I've come across the term "weaker set" when studying logic. I'd like to know what makes a set A of logic sentences "weaker" than a set B. Is it because A is smaller than B or is it because the set of every consequences of A is smaller than the set of every consequences of B?

Comment: @Shaun: you can prove *fewer* things in the weaker theory than you can in the stronger. E.g., in your example, you can't prove $\forall x \exists y (xy = 1)$ in semigroup theory, but you can in group theory.

Answer (score -1):

As I have seen the term used, a weaker statement follows as a direct consequence of the stronger statement. The stronger statement is more general and gives more information. You could say that the weaker statement is just one specific case of the stronger statement. For instance, consider the statements given below:

1. All even numbers greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
2. All odd numbers greater than 5 can be expressed as the sum of three primes.

The first statement is stronger, as it implies the second statement (just take one of the primes as 3) while the second doesn't necessarily imply the first statement.